# Mocking super method call using easymock

Tags: junit4, easymock

Is it possible to mock super class method call? I have seen many posts, but they are either irrelevant or using different testing framework.

Is it possible with easymock?

If not, what other framework would allow me to do it?

Comment: if not , how can i mock using other frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not. And I don't think it is with other frameworks. That would required bytecode manipulation of the base class. So maybe Powermock but I'm not sure.

However, I have never needed to do that in 20 years. In general, it means a bad implementation of the template pattern.

So instead of something like

```
public void foo() {
    // do stuff
    super.foo(); // don't forget to call super
    // do some other stuff
}
```

you better do

base class:

```
public void foo() {
    doBeforeFoo();
    // ... stuff that is in super
    doAfterFoo();
}
```

and then you fill the holes in the child class

Comment: Thanks to answer @Henr,y  and the way you suggest is also right but I am not supposed to touch the code I was thinking if its possible .

Comment: I tried using easymock's createmock builder method and I progressed in case where I m able to put same argument in expect Call which is being passed while method Call..  means when arguments matches it is mocked.. and the rule also says that for parameterized mocking.. now my problem is I am able to do it with an example code but when integrated with Project m not able to get same argument.. so it's giving missing behaviour definition exceptions,  as far as I understand.